# nginx reverse proxy to apache WebDAV server returns 0-byte files after uploading

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, apache-2.4, webdav

Setup:

client <-> nginx(:443 SSL) <-> apache(:80 WebDAV)

Client uploads file to webdav server.
Upload succeeds but file appears to be 0 bytes in size.
When SSHing in to apache server the file is confirmed to be 0 bytes.
If I connect to the apache server directly and upload a file everything works as expected. The file uploads and is the correct filesize and md5sum.

I've tried various settings on the nginx and apache server.
None of which are successfull.
I've googled numerous similar problems but cannot get it to work.
Some people say that you need to turn OFF webdav on the nginx server since apache is responsible for  all the webdav requests.
Could anyone confirm this statement ?

Nginx config:

```
   dav_access user:rw group:rw all:r;
   client_max_body_size 50M;
   create_full_put_path on;



    location / {

           dav_methods PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
           dav_ext_methods PROPFIND OPTIONS;

            set $destination $http_destination;

            if ($destination ~* ^https(.+)$) {
                    set $destination http$1;
            }


            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_set_header        Host                    drive.domain.com;
            proxy_set_header        Destination             $destination;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;
            add_header              Front-End-Https         on;

            proxy_pass http://webdav;

    }
```

Comment: did you manage to solve this? we are having exactly the same behavior with squid on pfsense + apache/dav on an internal server.

Comment: smember has provided an answer [here][1] and it works for me. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1110774/4736808